# In a Python Flask JWT, what is `sub`?

Tags: python, jwt

Here is an example JWT generated using the `Flask-JWT-Extended` library in Python 3:

```
{
    exp: 1628670229,
    fresh: false,
    iat: 1628666629,
    jti: "4ded281c-90a1-4a46-9360-2cbb7ac47926",
    nbf: 1628666629,
    sub: "17884f96-d4d5-43bd-9add-734340b761ac",
}
```

I can find documentation on all of these key/value pairs, except for `sub`. What is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to the JWT spec, `sub` is a Subject claim](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7519#section-4.1.2):

> The "sub" (subject) claim identifies the principal that is the
> subject of the JWT.  The claims in a JWT are normally statements
> about the subject.  The subject value MUST either be scoped to be
> locally unique in the context of the issuer or be globally unique.
> The processing of this claim is generally application specific.  The
> "sub" value is a case-sensitive string containing a StringOrURI
> value.  Use of this claim is OPTIONAL.

[Flask-JWT-Extended's documentation](https://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/stable/options/#JWT_IDENTITY_CLAIM) says it's the default key used to store the identity (user ID).

> **JWT_IDENTITY_CLAIM**
> The claim in a JWT that is used as the source of identity.
> Default: `"sub"`

Comment: Yeah, this is right, thank you. I thought that the `JTI` was the identifier for the subject, but it's actually the identifier for the JWT. Oops! In my vanilla use case, `sub` is the UUID of a user.